# What is the right regex to allow blank or numeric values

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to validate one variable named "Port" in my JavaScript to accept only either numerical digits or a blank value. I am not sure exactly what regex I can use to satisfy both conditions. Can anyone suggest me logic to use under my if loop to validate this?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. What validation do you use, HTML5 pattern?

Comment: Thanks, Will keep this things in my mind next time.

Comment: Why next time. Please update your question with relevant information  - for example post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve your goal with regexes, you are looking for:

```js
const regex = /^\d*$/;

console.log(regex.test("")); // true
console.log(regex.test("8080")); // true
console.log(regex.test("4d54")); // false
```